# get size of flex component

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have two components, one `Parent` and one `Child`. The latter should have `flex`-layout, so that it occupies 75% of the vertical space:

```js
const Parent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = (props) => {
    return (<View style={ styles.container }><MyChild /></View>)
}
const Child: FC<PropsWithChildren> = (props) => {
    return (<View style={ styles.childSytle }/>)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexdirection: 'column'
    },
    childStyle: { flex: 9 }
});
```

What I want to achieve now, is get the actual size of my `Child`-component from within `Parent`. Is it possible to get the size of a component, when it's `flex`?

I already tried a `forwardref` for my `Child` to get a reference to `Child`. However I have no idea how to get its size.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Parent() {
 return (
  //...
  <View>
   onLayout={event=>{
    const { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout
   }}
   <Child/>
  </View>
  //...
 )
```

You can retrieve the actual component width and height by implementing onLayout prop on the wrapper component of your child component. Then you should save them as either state or ref variable according use case.

Comment: Didn't you mean the `onLayout`-function to be defined on the `Child`-component? I want to get the `Child`s size, not the `Parent`s.